# Unhandled exception aborting python process on Windows, but not on OS X

Tags: python, multithreading, unhandled-exception

I have a Python service that opens a [Pika `BlockingConnection`](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/adapters/blocking.html) in a secondary thread, and listens to incoming messages.

When the connection to RabbitMQ is broken (if RabbitMQ dies, for example), an exception is raised, as it should. I do not catch the exception and let it go unhandled.

In Windows, when the exception is thrown, the process is terminated, which is what I want. In OS X, on the other hand, only the thread dies and the process keeps running.

How can I tell OS X to behave like Windows, or Windows to behave like OS X? I don't like this inconsistent behavior.

(Obviously I can catch the exception and terminate the process myself, but I'm asking about the default behavior)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior difference you describe makes me think that the thread is a daemon thread on OS X. Do you create it yourself, or it is created inside some third-party code? Can it be created as a daemonic or non-daemonic thread depending on OS?

Try checking what `isDaemon()` method returns (at least if `threading` interface is used).

Comment: I create the thread myself. Ooohh, I do call `setDaemon(True)` on the thread. That explains OS X's behavior, but not Windows' behavior.